# Run compilation safely in sandbox

Tags: security, compiling, sandbox

How to run compilation safely in sandbox?

If I download something from GitHub, how to be safe from malware when compiling it?

Linux (Ubuntu).

Comment: Presumably you intend to run it after compiling it; are you worried about malware then?

Answer (score 2):

You have several options (granted your system is 100% updated and doesn't contain locally exploitable vulnerabilities):

1. Create a separate user account and compile under it. Normally this account will only be able to access files in `/home/username` and various temp dirs, like `/tmp`.
2. Compile in chroot *after* dropping the root permissions (if you don't drop them, it's trivial to leave chroot).
3. Use `firejail`.
4. Compile in a virtual machine, VirtualBox/KVM/QEMU/etc - this is one of the safest options though hackers have found ways to exploit and leave hypervisors on multiple occasions.
5. The only 100% safe option would be to compile remotely on a different PC/server. E.g. [Linode](https://www.linode.com/?r=064e47ee0318ecf9288d855d48c54845e702d01a) allows to rent their servers and pay for them per hour (which is dirt cheap) - they have a huge number of distros to choose from including Debian, Ubuntu, Fedora, CentOS, Arch and others.

I would consider only options 3 and 4 to be akin to a sandbox.

Comment: You didn't really answer my question: Using a VM is a bad option. `firejail` would be good, but the essence of my question how _exactly_ to use it.